# Menu Link Transition CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to emulate the hover link effect for the menu as seen on this page:
https://www.paifma.com/

The code i am using on my page is:

http://beta.greekconcierge.com/login/

```
.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav>li {
    -webkit-transition-property: left, right;
    transition-property: left, right;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

1 - You have to set the initial property value and the final property value to make a transition work

2 - left and right are position properties, in order to achieve that effect I would make and additional div

```
height 1 
width 0 
disp. inline-block 
center aligned
```

and on hover you make that div `width 100%` (using transitions as well)

Comment: the example doesn't seem to have any divs. Also it will be hard to implement additional html code. There should be a way of doing this with the current structure..